# Date formating issue when using momentjs and bootstrap calendar

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a function that return an array of objects that is used as parameter for a bootstrap calendar.  The problem is when i create event_data.start. If i use start_date.year() in the end the calendar will not work because of invalid date. If I put 2013 (or any integer), then it works. 
I used a breakpoint at that line, start_date.year() always return 2013.

```
var start_date = moment(reminder.start_date);
var stop_date = moment(reminder.stop_date);
var reminder_time = moment(reminder.time, 'HH:MM:ss');

while (start_date.unix() < stop_date.unix()) {
   start_date = moment(start_date.year()+ '-' + start_date.month().toString() +'-'+start_date.add('days', 1).date());
   event_data.start = new Date(parseInt(start_date.year()), 9, 25 - 3, 16, 0);
   events_array.push(event_data); //events_array then used for calendar
}
```

I am thinking the start_date object is used as some kind of reference and the actual value is not passed or something. Hope you can give me an idea.

Comment: Found it after all. In javascript native code, months are 1 indexed (from 1 to 12) and in momentjs months are 0 indexed (form 0 to 11)

Comment: Actually, both moment *and* native javascript use months 0-11 when used as a number and 1-12 when used in a string.  That's in the documentation for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing entirely too much manual string manipulation in this code.  If you're using moment.js, then you should work *with* the API instead of working *against* it.  Try something like this:

```
while (start_date.isBefore(stop_date)) {
   start_date.add('days', 1);
   event_data.start = start_date.clone().toDate();
   events_array.push(event_data);
}
```

I used `.clone()` because I'm uncertain how you will be using the date in your object.  You may find that it is not necessary depending on what you are doing.

Then there's some weirdness in your code to deal with.  First, you define `reminder_time` but don't use it for anything, so I'm not sure why it is there.

Then, you had this line:

```
event_data.start = new Date(parseInt(start_date.year()), 9, 25 - 3, 16, 0);
```

That would be only using the year part of the `start_date` and hard-coding the rest to October 22 16:00.  I'm not sure why at all you would do that, so I omitted it from the above code.  If that's actually what you wanted to do, then do it like this instead:

```
event.start = start_date.clone().month(9).date(22).startOf('day').hour(16).toDate();
```

Here you *definitely* need to use `.clone()` because otherwise the manipulation of value would interfere with your loop logic.